# Magento Secure url https://

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9 version to my Ecommerce site In that i am setting secure url (https://) in all page is it good practice or it have any drawbacks for that can you please guide me

my all page url should be `https://domain.com`.  But I didn't use `https://www.domain.com`

Can you please suggest me

Comment: Please read it again i m asking site url which means www also

Comment: your base_url is the answer, you can use www or not, and then redirect in .htaccess to avoid any duplicate content

Comment: ok but i need more explanation on that can you please give it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SSL everywhere should not have any drawbacks if your server is configured properly.

Non-www and www should not have any impact on your SEO unless you have duplicates. Make sure you redirect one to the other and make sure they are not both displaying the same content.